# Testng Tests not Executing after adding Rally Rest API into Pom

Tags: java, testng, jenkins-plugins, rally

Am using TestNg framework to execute my test suite and i am trying to integrate test results into Rally.

When am adding Rally Rest API dependency into my pom.xml file after that  when i execute my test case, before suite and after suite is executing but my Test case is not executing ?  can anyone help on this ?

Explanation :

I am using testng framework to execute my test cases, and after its complete , I like to update test results into Rally.

For integration with Rally, I have downloaded Rally Rest API into my application.

Rally Rest API will update the test results into Rally. In local its working fine but when i am trying to run from jenkins

I am getting error `"package com.rallydev.rest does not exist"`

So I have added dependency into my Pom.xml file and while running ,Before suite is executting then it goes to afterSuite but actual test not execute.

Comment: Please add more details or this question would be closed in sometime.

Comment: 1. Am using testng framework to execute my test case and after its complete , i like to update test results into Rally

Comment: 1. Am using testng framework to execute my test case and after its complete , i like to update test results into Rally   2. For integration with Rally, i have downloaded Rally Rest API  into my application. 3. Rally Rest API will update the test results into Rally 4. In local its working fine and when i am trying to run from jenkins am getting error " package com.rallydev.rest does not exist" 5. So i have added dependency into my Pom.xml file  and while running ,before suite is execution then its goes to after suite but actual test not executing -- this is the issue

Comment: I have added your explanation in question. Also please share your error if you are getting any, seems like your test is failing in BeforeSuite only and thus not executing test method. It looks like a configuration issue, but we cant be sure until you share your error details and some code details.

Comment: am  able to run before suite without any issues and it should go to test method to execute test but in my case ,its going to after suite. but if i remove rally rest api from pom.xml file then its working as expected.